# Convert On Page text to HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some text on a web page that I would like to render in to HTML. The text looks like this:

```
<p>
    <span style="font-family: Arial">
        <span style="font-size: x-small">
            <img border="5" hspace="10" alt="" align="left" width="200" height="150" src="/Solutions/image/Lighthouse.jpg" />
```

I would like to show it as HTML ie. with the elements rendered correctly. It is set into a `span` with an ID:

```
<span class="VIEWBOX" id="_Datasoln_solutiondetails">
```

How can this be achieved using jQuery or Javascript?

Comment: Where is the text? in a variable? textarea?

Comment: It is just printed as text after the span tag

Comment: If the text is put into your HTML file then... it already is HTML? I are confused.

Comment: I'm still not clear on exactly what you want to do.  Is the text currently not rendering because "<" and ">" have been replaced with "&lt;" and "&gt;"?  What is producing the text?

Comment: Iare confubled too, can't make it out but there it is as clear as day just printed on the page as text

Comment: If the text is coming from something like ASP.Net (which I'm guessing from the format of the `span`), then maybe try HTML decoding the string before writing it: eg `<%= Server.HtmlDecode(myString) %>`

Comment: thought of that unfortunately the app is using a txt editor and is writing the above to the db, and after that I have no control of the loaded page except to inject some JS - hence the question

Comment: Hey people...why would you down-vote a question like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you saying that the rendered HTML on your page looks like this, when the page has loaded?

```
<p>
  <span style="font-family: Arial">
    <span style="font-size: x-small">
       <img border="5" hspace="10" alt="" align="left" width="200" height="150" src="/Solutions/image/Lighthouse.jpg" />
    [missing /span]
  [missing /span]
[missing /p]
```

Or is that just the html or text that gets prepared somewhere in your programming/scripting process?

To answer this question, I presume you already have that text/html somewhere on your web page.

---

So in that case, if you can't control how the above html snippet gets on your page, you could get jQuery to transform the code. And there will be some Kung-Fu fighting,

Are you saying that you already have the SPAN with the ID? Or would you inject (or append it) to the existing HTML?

```
<span class="VIEWBOX" id="_Datasoln_solutiondetails">
```

For now, I'm guessing the SPAN with the ID does not yet exist. In that case, do something along these lines:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Library Contents</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
 // GET THE IMAGE AS A REFERENCE POINT
 var x = $("img[src='/Solutions/image/Lighthouse.jpg']");
 // TEST
//      $(x).hide();

//  GET THE IMAGE HTML TAG
var htmlStr = $(x).parent().html();
//  TEST
console.log("htmlStr: " + htmlStr);

//  DESIRED HTML
var newHtml = '<span class="VIEWBOX" id="_Datasoln_solutiondetails">' + htmlStr + '</span>';
//  TEST
// console.log("newHtml: " + newHtml);
$(x).parent().parent().replaceWith(newHtml);
 });  
 </script>
</head>
<body>
  <p>
    <span style="font-family: Arial">
      <span style="font-size: x-small">
        <img border="5" hspace="10" alt="" align="left" width="200" height="150" src="/Solutions/image/Lighthouse.jpg" />
      </span>
    </span>
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to do this, with javascript:

```
varname.replace(/<(span|p) [a-zA-Z0-9=":; -/]+>/g, /<$1 id="newid" class="newclass">/g);
```

You can change span|p to span|p|b|img etc to pick up other tags that you would like.

**Update:**

```
var str = '<p> <span style="font-family: Arial"><span style="font-size: x-small"><img border="5" hspace="10" alt="" align="left" width="200" height="150" src="/Solutions/image/Lighthouse.jpg" />';
var newvar = str.replace(/<(span|p) [a-zA-Z0-9=":; -/]+>/g, /<$1 id="newid" class="newclass">/g);
alert(newvar);
```